# Need to transfer app build from developer to myself Bundle ID and Provisioning Profile transfer?

Tags: provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier

I had an app created for me--Demeter's Harvest (iOS). The company that built it has dropped off the map, so I can't get them to help me with this.

I get a message when I try to access it all that reads: An App ID with Identifier 'info.NAMEOFDEVELOPER.demeter' is not available. Please enter a different string." and another one for the Bundle ID that shows the Identifier 'info.ORIGINALDEVNAME.demeter' with the version and build.

I placed my name into the team area, and got a message that says no non-expired provisioning profiles are installed with a "Fix Issue" button.

How do I go about gaining access to my app code (if that is what it does) so I can get a new developer to make changes and updates to it?

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 0):

You're likely up a creek here. If you don't have your app code there's no way anyone can help you gain access to it except the developer.

Regarding the bundleID it will be tied to whichever Dev Portal created it. If you own that portal you're fine. If the developer owns that portal and they either don't renew their account or block you from accessing it there will be no way for you to re-use it.

Comment: I have the code. They did send it before they ended up disappearing. It was sent to me. How do I check to determine what Dev Portal created it?

Comment: If you don't have access to their Apple Dev Portal then they "own" that bundle ID. The developer would have to grant you access to it but even that is a band-aid as the portal would have to be maintained/paid for, etc. You're better off using a new BundleID and taking the hit.

Comment: I have the code. They did send it before they ended up disappearing. It was sent to me. How do I check to determine what Dev Portal created it? The provisioning profile mentioned does appear in my dev portal. That means it's all in my name, right?

Comment: How do I change the bundle and "take the hit"? I don't know what that means. Sorry. Very new to this and my first coding class in C++ starts in 3 weeks.

Comment: Do you see the BundleID in your portal?

Comment: I see App IDs, but can't locate anythign that says Bundle ID. Where would that be?

Comment: They're the same thing

Comment: Oh! Okay. I see three provisioning files for the app with the same App ID: info. DEVELOPERNAME.demeter. One is with XC in front and then there's a Wild Card.